# How to add images to products in Magento 1.8.1?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Where can I add some nice images for my products I've got in my onlineshop?
I'm using Firexox and magento 1.8.1 in Windows XP (VM)
As I was looking the YouTube tuts, there were such an "Upload-Button" in Product -> edit -> on the left hand side to images. Unfortunately, I can see no such button.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may take few seconds to show the "Browse Files.." and "Upload Files" button.

OR

Try install/update your flash plugin or use Chrome to upload images

(Magento using Flash to upload images. )

---------------Admin Login in Chrome-----------------

I think there is the problem with session cookie with the chrome browser. 
So just go through this directory /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file 
and comment out the line from 88 to 94 in magento (1.8.1.0 for my case). Like this

```
// session cookie params
/* $cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
    'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

*/
after that try to make login from your backend.

---

While working in Magento in development mode(not in production mode) first disable the cache (site will become slow), as sometimes you don't get the result for the updated one.

Comment: I cannot log in from Chrome nor form the IE, but I try to update the flash plugin.

Comment: For login in chrome you have can disable some code, as it is too long I'm writing the solution in a separate anwser .

Answer (score 1):

When you go to `Product -> edit` as you said, click on the `images` tab on the left, and you can easily upload product images.

Comment: There is no button. That's my problem

Comment: Can you provide a printscreen?